# Horizontal scroll not working on chrome iPad

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, ipad

I have created a horizontal scrolling website but for some reason chrome on ipad shrinks the entire layout to show it without enabling horizontal scroll.

I have created a [test file](http://theprojectstagingserver.com/horizontal-test.html) to replicate this issue with following code:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

            <!-- Title -->
            <title>Testing Horziontal Scroll</title>

            <!-- For responsive behavior -->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0">

            <style>
                .horizontal{
                    height: 500px;
                    width: 4000px;
                }
                .item{
                    width: 1000px; background: #f00; float: left; height:100%;
                }
                .item:nth-child(2){
                    background: #0f0;
                }
                .item:nth-child(3){
                    background: #00f;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="horizontal">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I tried removing view port meta tag and it fixed the issue but that created issues on other devices.

Comment: have you tried to add in the css overflow: scroll; ?

Comment: on body or html? I will try on both right now.

Comment: I tried it didn't work.

Comment: In my iPad our example work's fine, what version of iOS are you using?

Comment: I am not sure how to check iOS version but in general setting in about tab it says 9.2 (13c75) - it's an iPad mini

Comment: the issue is only in chrome... iPad safari is working as expected. btw chrome version is 47.0.2526.107

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the following to your CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

This will force the overflow to the left and right to be set to being scrolled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ImranBughio Sadly, I no longer have an iPad around at the moment, but you could also try adding this property  `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to the body CSS